# Load Frames from packages

Tags: delphi, dynamic, bpl, tframe

I have three frames inside separate three bpls,

in my main application i have created three buttons and , i want to call the frames dynamically(one at a time )when the respective button is clicked (the frame can be shown in any control eg : TPanal)

i have already done such a thing using Dlls but some in the Stack overflow community recommended me to use bpl (they said it is easy  ),
[my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985256/how-to-use-delphi-dlls-without-enabling-build-with-runtime-packages)

Comment: i think there may be a easier solution than using dll

Comment: in the other post xbasic explained you very well what to do. post some code, or edit the question so we can understand what you're asking.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994629/load-tframe-from-bpl-to-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there's an article about loading a form from a package (bpl file): http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178
The same should work for frames.

And maybe the most important of all, understand the difference between a bpl and a plain dll: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/bpl_vs_dll.htm

God bless